# When using an image as a button how can I ignore the transparent parts when detecting a click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2d game with my brother in Unity and I am working on the interactive map (Using pixel art). I want to place different territory images together like puzzle pieces, but when it detects a click on a territory I don't want the transparent parts of the image to be detected.

I am a beginner and need some help with this. Any help is appreciated.

Example of the map and overlap.
[image: Example of the map and overlap.]

Comment: You say "but when it detects a click on a territory I don't want the transparent parts of the image to be detected". Do you mean that when you click the transparent part of an image, it is being selected (and you dont want that)?

Comment: @MTLaurentys Yes that's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use `Image.alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold`.

As said in [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold.html):

> The alpha threshold specifies the minimum alpha a pixel must have for
>   the event to considered a "hit" on the Image.

So you just got to add a script that changes this property for the images you want to ignore the click in transparent parts. It could be something like:

```
public Image image;

void Start()
{
    //Any desired value between 0 and 1.
    image.alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold = 0.5f;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering but I found out what I did wrong. I was using an image when I should have been using a sprite. Now when I add the polygon collider it works perfectly. If I've figured out the problem how do I close the question?

Comment: It would be nice to post your solution for your own question and accept it as the best answer. By doing this, other people with the same issue may find this solution.
It may take a day or two before you can select your own answer as the best one.

Comment: @b.galerani your solution looks way more clear than adding a polygon collider. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a box and it is selected, the sprite (visual part of the box) does not matter. It all relies on the algorithm that "connects" the mouse and the game. It is more simple than it sounds.

As you use unity you will rarely deal with that algorithm but you have to understand it in order to implement your own code. The way it works is (probably - but always depends on your implementation) is that your "territory" has a "collision" component. At that component you selected it can interact with the mouse and then you implemented that interaction.

At this point if you do not do anything special, every part of the collision shape will trigger the same effect. That makes sense. So, now, to solve your issue...

1. You have to find a way (an algorithm) to detect only given parts of the collision shape and complete the interaction if the mouse is in those parts.

OR

2. You have to fix your collision shape so that it matches the actual "image". That means using a polygon with several vertices and manually matching it with your sprite.

You can do either one depending on the situation. As exercise do number 1 this time (also, as the borders are chaotic). It is NOT hard. Think with me, if every transparent area has the same "Color", if you can check which pixel of the image was clicked, then you just need to know what is the color at that point. You can try for different solutions as well.

A bonus is to make is work if the actual "image" has a transparent area.

Comment: I tried to detect the color of the mouse position when clicked, but for some reason the color varied across the territory so it didn't work. For the second option, do you know how to use a Polygon Collider 2D for detecting clicks?